# gunicorn and django project (no app)

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a django project, and I want to deploy it with gunicorn/nginx.
But I use settings.py urls.py views.py directly without start a django app, and gunicorn needs application name.

How can I deploy a django project which has no app.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an application name with gunicorn_django command. just run gunicorn_django command in your projetc folder or tel him the path of settings

http://gunicorn.org/run.html#gunicorn-django