# run_gunicorn works but not gunicorn_django despite both within the same environment, can't see registration module

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have an issue here where I did "gunicorn_django" but it says `"ImportError: No module named registration"`

However, when I do `python manage.py run_gunicorn`, it runs perfectly.

One way I did to verify that gunicorn_django and registration are both in the same environment is that, when I deactivate it, I run gunicorn_django, it returns command not found and when I did python and try to import registration, it is not found as well.

However, when i did use the virtualenv "workon projectname", both "gunicorn_django" and "import registration" works.

Anything i can do? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

It's the new django 1.4 project structure.

So I workaround it by doing this in my supervisor.conf

```
command=/sites/.virtualenvs/<project>/bin/python /sites/<domain>/code/<project>/manage.py run_gunicorn -c /sites/<domain>/code/<project>/configs/prod/gunicorn.conf.py
```

Comment: dude you saved lot of my time. Thanks for this. If you can post the same answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455883/django-gunicorn-wsgi I will be happy to give you the bounty.