# Django Gunicorn wsgi

Tags: python, django, wsgi, gunicorn

Hi I am trying to integrate my django 1.4.1 app with Gunicorn 0.14.6. I start gunicorn server from command line like so -

```
gunicorn -c /home/code/gunicorn_config.py
```

I get this traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 99, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 101, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 24, in load
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 292, in import_app
    app = eval(obj, mod.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'application' is not defined
```

Where am i going wrong? Whats this `application` variable & where do I need to modify this?

Also since I am using Django1.4.1 I have a `wsgi.py` file already in my project, do I need to change that?

**UPDATE:** here is my `gunicorn_config.py` file contents -

```
import os
import sys
import multiprocessing

def app_path():
    sys.path.append('/home/code/po/')
    sys.path.append('/home/code/po/ball/')
    return

def num_cpus():
    cpus = 0
    try:
        cpus = os.sysconf("SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN")
    except:
        cpus =  multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    if cpus: return cpus
    else: return 3

#defining the behavior of gunicorn
app_path()

bind      = "127.0.0.1:8080"
workers   = num_cpus()*2 + 1
debug     = True
daemon    = False
accesslog = '/home/code/logs/guni_access.log'
errorlog  = '/home/code/logs/guni_error.log'
loglevel  = 'debug'
django_settings  = '/home/code/po/po/'
pythonpath       = '/home/code/po/'
```

@moopet - i dont even think that `wsgi.py` file is called, how do i make gunicorn pick that file ?

Comment: can you add gunicorn_config.py file too. It seems like your wsgi.py path is not right.

Comment: Paste the wsgi.py file in. It should be where application is defined

Comment: @moopet - i dont even think that `wsgi.py` file is called, how do i make gunicorn pick that file ?

Comment: If it's a Django app, you could start it with `gunicorn_django`, not `gunicorn`.

Comment: using `gunicorn_django` does not help either. Plus somewhere I read that when one is using Django1.4.x you are better off using `gunicorn`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `django_settings` is incorrect. `django_settings` should be in the form of a python module import that is importable from the Python path you set. So

```
pythonpath = '/home/code/po'
django_settings = 'po.settings'
```

To elaborate a bit more, `application` is the default variable (which should be a WSGI application object) gunicorn will try and import from the Python module that you supply.

So to think about it another way. Say you were trying to run a simple Flask wsgi appication. The actual WSGI app was defined as `application` and lived inside `/home/code/views.py`. Then the following would manually start serving it with gunicorn

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/code
gunicorn -w 2 views:application
```

So the variable application inside the views module. You can read about how [Django provides you with the application object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/).

It might be that you need to point gunicorn at the `po.wsgi` module itself. It's a little hard to tell from the information provided so far. If that module was created properly it should contain a variable called `application`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I still get the same error. I think gunicorn is not able to find the wsgi.py file and hence `application` is not set. How do I make sure gunicorn knows about wsgi.py ?

Comment: Assuming your wsgi.py file is `/home/code/po/po/wsgi.py` and it contains a WSGI app called `application`, what happens if you run `export PYTHONPATH=/home/code/po; gunicorn -w 2 po.wsgi:application` from a shell?

Comment: giving it to you as its better to give it to someone who helped rather than reputation going to waste...

Comment: Thanks Srikar, did you get it working in the end? Do you want to post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check if another package you have installed already contains a file called wsgi.py. (gevent does.) If so, likely the wrong wsgi.py file is being loaded. Try renaming your wsgi.py file to something else (e.g. app_wsgi.py) and add run your app using

```
gunicorn -c /home/code/gunicorn_config.py app_wsgi
```